# Toggle between two themes using one key binding

Tags: themes

When I press the `F9` key I want to call the `ef-themes-select` function and when I press `F9` a second time to call the `modus-themes-select` function. I want to toggle between them each time I press the F9 key.

Both functions bring up a minibuffer completion in which a new theme can be selected. So, the first time I press `F9`, `ef-themes-select` will display a minibuffer to select a different Ef theme. The second time I press `F9`, `modus-themes-select` should be called. However, we need to take into consideration the second time `F9` is pressed it is issued in the minibuffer that opened first.

```lisp
    (use-package ef-themes
      :init
      (load-theme 'ef-summer t)
      :bind ("<f9>" . my/select-themes))
    
    (use-package modus-themes
      :bind ("<f9>" . my/select-themes))
```

Can someone help me write this function to do the behavior I'm looking for?

```lisp
    (defun my/select-themes ()
    ;; ...
    )
```

The function doesn't need to remember the theme that is currently active, just call the functions in a toggling manner.

Comment: Are you sure you'd prefer this 'design'? Because the common approach for calling two different variants of a function is by using a [universal argument](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrefixArgument).

Comment: And if it's just one variant, can the F key be used? Then I'll use two different F keys instead.

Comment: Well @sds provided a nice answer already, of course. If always calling modus-themes-select first, and if calling ef-themes-select directly after it causes no further problems, e.g. that a second minibuffer gets opened or you see a message 'attempt to open another minibuffer from minibuffer', then the repeated F9 key solution is fine; it could even get adapted so that it closes the first mini-buffer before opening the second (which is probably what your comment about it is hinting at). I was just indicating the common alternative approach (which does not automatically mean the best approach)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`last-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs///manual/html_node/elisp/Command-Loop-Info.html):

```lisp
(defun my/select-themes ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq last-command 'my/select-themes)
      (modus-themes-select)
    (ef-themes-select)))
```

If this design (<kbd>F9</kbd> for `ef-themes-select` and <kbd>F9 F9</kbd> for `modus-themes-select`) is what you want, this is the way to go.

If you want <kbd>F9</kbd> to run `ef-themes-select` and <kbd>C-u F9</kbd> to run `modus-themes-select`, you can use [Prefix Command Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html):

```lisp
(defun my/select-themes (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if arg
      (modus-themes-select)
    (ef-themes-select)))
```

Comment: Thank you. A user mentioned above that using universal argument is better. I'm not sure what he meant by that. Is it a problem that I bind the function to an F key? As far as I know F5-F9 is free for the user to bind.

Comment: @Zoli: see edit

Comment: The first is the one I want. Thank you.